Spring Cloud Kinesis KCL enabled use high cpu in AWS ECS instance (fargate)
I use spring-cloud-stream-binder-kinesis version 4.0.4 with KCL enabled.
Java 17 with spring boot version 3.0.1
One instance of spring boot in ECS (fargate) 4cpu and 8ram
Problem is with kcl enabled (KclMessageDrivenChannelAdapter class), cpu goes very high for long time and AWS kill process.
If kcl disabled, we use KinesisMessageDrivenChannelAdapter class.
Here is the following yaml conf:
    stream:
      kinesis:
        binder:
          auto-create-stream: false
          kpl-kcl-enabled: true
        bindings:
          processEvent-in-0:
            consumer:
              shard-iterator-type: LATEST
              listener-mode: batch
              records-limit: 4000
              idle-between-polls: 45000
              polling-max-records: 4000
              polling-idle-time: 45000
              checkpoint-interval: 45000
              checkpoint-mode: batch
              fan-out: false
      bindings:
        processEvent-in-0:
          group: myapp
          destination: stream1,stream2
          content-type: application/json
          binder: kinesis
          consumer:
            multiplex: true
            use-native-decoding: true
            batch-mode: true
          error-handler-definition: errorHandler

Any ideas ?
Conf issue?
Spring integration aws issue ?
I suspect KCL thread pool from spring integration which cause this issue.
But even reducing the thread pool, cpu goes high (70%) for long time.
I see that amazon-kinesis-client is used by kcl in spring cloud kinesis lib. And the scheduler class has unlimited pool thread for its executor service:
@Data
@KinesisClientInternalApi
public class SchedulerCoordinatorFactory implements CoordinatorFactory {
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public ExecutorService createExecutorService() {
        return new SchedulerThreadPoolExecutor(
                new ThreadFactoryBuilder().setNameFormat("ShardRecordProcessor-%04d").build());
    }

    static class SchedulerThreadPoolExecutor extends ThreadPoolExecutor {
        private static final long DEFAULT_KEEP_ALIVE = 60L;
        SchedulerThreadPoolExecutor(ThreadFactory threadFactory) {
            super(0, Integer.MAX_VALUE, DEFAULT_KEEP_ALIVE, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new SynchronousQueue<>(),
                    threadFactory);
        }
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public ShardRecordProcessorCheckpointer createRecordProcessorCheckpointer(@NonNull final ShardInfo shardInfo,
                                                                              @NonNull final Checkpointer checkpoint) {
        return new ShardRecordProcessorCheckpointer(shardInfo, checkpoint);
    }
}

